# Toggle icon flips no matter what section is opened

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am new to all of this so please excuse any misuse of terms.

I have added a toggle to my wordpress site to hide long sections of text and it seems to work just fine.

I wanted to add an arrow that flips depending on whether the section is open or not. My problem is the arrow flips back and forth no matter what section is toggled and I don't know how to fix that.

JS:

```
function toggle(id) {
var element = document.getElementById(id);
var text = document.getElementById("arrow");
if (element) {
    var display = element.style.display;

    if (display == "none") {
        element.style.display = "block";
      text.innerHTML = "&#9650;";

    } else {
        element.style.display = "none";
      text.innerHTML = "&#x25bc;";
    }
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<h4>Procedure</h4>
<h4 onclick="toggle('telnetPrint')">Telnet<a id="arrow">&#x25bc;</a></h4>
<div id="telnetPrint" style="display: none;">
<ol>
<li>fjkldsaj;lkf</li>
</ol>
<h4 onclick="toggle('telnetPrint')">Hide -</h4>
</div>
<p> </p>
<h4 onclick="toggle('linuxPrint')">Linux Computer&#x25bc;</h4>
<div id="linuxPrint" style="display: none">
<ol>
<li>fjkldsjfklsa</li>
</ol>
<h4 onclick="toggle('linuxPrint')">Hide -</h4>
</div>
```

If anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

p.s. no jQuery please

Comment: Is there supposed to be an arrow for each section? Looks like there's only one arrow from what I can see

Comment: Yes there is supposed to be an arrow for each section. I just forgot to change the second one before I posted this.

Comment: I see. Did nobody resolve this issue? If one of the answers worked you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: Oh, thank you; I didn't know I needed to mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are calling the same "arrow". You only have arrow set for Telnet. You can add an arrow as well to linuxPrint. I would ID them as :

```
<a id="arrowtelnetPrint"></a>
```

and

```
<a id="arrowlinuxPrint"></a>
```

That way you can use the "id" to change the correct one. Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ezdrhLtr/2/

This will have the full code, with minor adjustments, that toggle both arrows.

Comment: Also, this is pure js.

Comment: Thank you so much; I was completely stumped. You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

`var text = document.getElementById("arrow");`
you are referencing an element with `id` 'arrow'. Everytime the toggle function is executed, you will flip the element with `id` 'arrow'. What you can do is pass a boolean value to know if its to be flipped or not

```
<h4 onclick="toggle('telnetPrint',true)">Telnet<a id="arrow">&#x25bc;</a></h4>
```

and in your script

```
function toggle(id, flipOrNot) {
var element = document.getElementById(id);
var text = document.getElementById("arrow");
if (element) {
    var display = element.style.display;

    if (display == "none") {
        element.style.display = "block";   
        if(flipOrNot){

           text.innerHTML = "&#9650;";
        }

    } else {
        element.style.display = "none";
      if(flipOrNot){

          text.innerHTML = "&#x25bc;";
      }
    }
}
}
```

for other elements, you can do

```
<h4 onclick="toggle('linuxPrint',false)">Hide -</h4>
```

to prevent flip